# AWS Mobile Hub states user is not signed-in after custom UI User Pool sign-in/authentication

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub, aws-userpools

I'm currently using AWS Mobile Hub for an iOS application that utilizes Cognito and Cloud Logic.

I decided to replace the default AuthUIViewController because I didn't like how it looked. I used this sample project to help me implement sign up through User Pools: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift .

Here is my implementation:

Starting in my AppDelegate, I set the UserPool I want to sign into to a commonly accessible constant variable. One idea I have to why AWSMobileClient doesn't think my user is signed in is because it defines its own service configuration/pool, but I'm not sure:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions     launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    AWSDDLog.add(AWSDDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)
    AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose

    // setup service configuration
    let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: Constants.AWS.CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion, credentialsProvider: nil)

    // create pool configuration
    let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: Constants.AWS.CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId,
                                                                    clientSecret: Constants.AWS.CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret,
                                                                    poolId: Constants.AWS.CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)

    // initialize user pool client
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

    // fetch the user pool client we initialized in above step
    Constants.AWS.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
        application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
        launchOptions)
}
```

After the AppDelegate is finished, the application goes to its root view controller named InitialViewController. Here, I allow the user to click a facebook sign in or regular (user pool) sign in.

```
class InitialViewController:UIViewController {

@objc func regLogin() {
 //Set a shared constants variable "user" to the current user   
 if (Constants.AWS.user == nil) {
        Constants.AWS.user = Constants.AWS.pool?.currentUser()
    }
    Constants.AWS.pool?.delegate = self

    //This function calls the delegate function startPasswordAuthentication() in the extension below to initiate login
        Constants.AWS.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    //called after details for user are successfully retrieved after login                
                print(AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn)// false
                print(AWSSignInManager.init().isLoggedIn)// false
                print(AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.init().isLoggedIn())// false
                print(Constants.AWS.user?.isSignedIn) // true
                AppDelegate.del().signIn()
            })
            return nil
        }
      }
    }

extension InitialViewController: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate {

func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
    self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return self.loginVC
}
}
```

As you can see, the functions do their job and the user is successfully logged in according to (Constants.AWS.user?.isSignedIn) as well as the fact that I am successfully able to retrieve the user details. However, when I ask AWSSignInManager or the UserPoolsSignInProvider whether my user is logged in, it returns false. This is a problem because without AWSMobileHub seeing my user as logged in, I cannot access my Cloud Logic functions etc.

Can someone please help me shed light on how I can notify MobileHub and the sign in manager that my user is logged into the user pool so that my application can work right?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan's answer is a good starting point for this, but it requires to include AWSAuthUI to your project.

A better solution is to implement directly the functions in AWSUserPoolsUIOperations.m. In particular, the function triggered when pressing the sign in button, should look like this:

```
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.usernameTextField.text != nil && self.passwordTextField.text != nil) {

        self.userName = self.usernameTextField.text!
        self.password = self.passwordTextField.text!

        AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setInteractiveAuthDelegate(self)

        AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().login(
            signInProviderKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().identityProviderName,
            completionHandler: { (provider: Any?, error: Error?) in
                print(AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn)
        })
   } else {
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Missing information",
                                                message: "Please enter a valid user name and password",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
       let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
       alertController.addAction(retryAction)
   }
}
```

Then include the following functions as an extension of your SignIn view controller:

```
public func handleUserPoolSignInFlowStart() {
    let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: self.userName!, password: self.password!)
    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
}

public func startPasswordAuthentication() -> AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {
    return self
}

public func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
}

public func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                    message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(retryAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
        } else {
            self.usernameTextField.text = nil
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging more through the AWS code, I found my answer in the pod AWSAuthUI in AWSSignInViewController.m (The view controller used in the default authentication process for mobile hub/cognito).

The code is:

```
- (void)handleUserPoolSignIn {
    Class awsUserPoolsUIOperations = NSClassFromString(USERPOOLS_UI_OPERATIONS);
    AWSUserPoolsUIOperations *userPoolsOperations = [[awsUserPoolsUIOperations alloc] initWithAuthUIConfiguration:self.config];
    [userPoolsOperations loginWithUserName:[self.tableDelegate getValueForCell:self.userNameRow forTableView:self.tableView]
                                  password:[self.tableDelegate getValueForCell:self.passwordRow forTableView:self.tableView]
                      navigationController:self.navigationController
                         completionHandler:self.completionHandler];
}
```

and getting to just the parts that matter... in Swift!!

```
 userPoolsOperations.login(withUserName: "foo", password: "bar", navigationController: self.navigationController!, completionHandler: { (provider: Any?, error: Error?) in
            print(AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn) // true
            print(AWSSignInManager.init().isLoggedIn) // false
            print(AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.init().isLoggedIn()) // false
            print(Constants.AWS.user?.isSignedIn) // nil
            })
        }
```

lesson learned: Reading through AWS's code is helpful even though it sucks